# Pasar una variable de un controlador a una vista (laravel, jquery, mysql)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

La cosa está así, un compañero me pasa un código donde crea una un botón mediante una variable que se ubica en un controlador y no tengo ni idea de como la puedo llamar en la sección de scripts en mi vista para que la misma muestre un modal

la parte del código que mencioné:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $data = Country::all();
            return datatables()->of($data)
            ->addColumn('action', function($row){
                $btn = '<a href="javascript:editCountry()" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                return $btn;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make();
        }
        return view('mantenimientos.country.index');
    }
```

Ese código es del controlador, ahora lo quiero llamar a mi vista pero no sé.
Script en donde quiero que se use el botón:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('edit btn').on('click', function() {
      $('.modalEdit').modal('show');

      $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

      var data = $tr.children("td").map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
      }).get();

      console.log(data);

      $('#id').val(data[0]);
      $('#name').val(data[1]);
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun tu codigo del controlador estas utilizando el paquete de [yajra/datatables](http://yajra%20/%20laravel-datatables)

Si te pasaron el codigo debes instalar dicho paquete por medio de composer el comando es 
 `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle:"~9.0"`


Tu funcion `index()` devuelve una vista `view('mantenimientos.country.index');` eso quitalo de ahi porque en los datatables de yajra devuelve una collect de datos que los utilizas para llenar una tabla por ajax mas abajo agrego la funcion, asi que reemplaza la funcion index() por la siguiente:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
            $data = Country::all();
            return datatables()->of($data)
            ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                return '<a href="javascript:editCountry()" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make();
        
    }
```

Luego crea una ruta que te lleve tu vista `view('mantenimientos.country.index');` en la que supongo que tienes una tabla en esa tablas vas a graficar todo el contenido de te devuelve la funcion de index de tu controlador

entonces en tu vista (`mantenimientos.country.index`) debes colocar el siguiente codigo reemplazando la información por la de tu tabla de Country
recuerda que debes haber creado una ruta para que acceder a tu funcion `index()` en mi caso es la ruta `{{ url('fill_country') }}`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    fill_datatable();
});

    function fill_datatable(){
        var dataTable = $('#country').DataTable({
            serverSide: false,
            ajax:{
                url: "{{ url('fill_country') }}"
            },
            columns: [
                { data:'id', name:'No.Orden' },
                { data:'estado_compra', name:'Estado' },
                { data:'action', name:'Acción' }
            ]
        });
    }
```

No cambie al reemplazar las columanas la ultima fila que es `{ data:'action', name:'Acción' }` porque ahi es donde va el boton del controlador para tu vista!

En ese punto ya tiene los datos de retorna tu funcion a los de tu vista para poder graficar la tabla y poder utilizar tu funcion javascript